# How to make WebStorm Reformat Code according to ESLint?

Tags: typescript, next.js, eslint, webstorm

I've recently set up a fresh [Next.js App Router project with MUI](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/tree/master/examples/material-ui-nextjs-ts), and I'm using WebStorm 2023.2.4 with the *Visual Studio Code* keymap for my development workflow. My issue lies in code formatting using the <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> shortcut in WebStorm.

In my project, there was already a `.eslintrc.json` file included by default. I've made a small adjustment to enforce 2-space indentation in my code, like this:

```json
{
  "extends": "next/core-web-vitals",
  "rules": {
    "indent": ["error", 2]
  }
}
```

Now, when I use the <kbd>ALT</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd> shortcut for code reformatting, WebStorm appears to apply a 4-space indentation instead of the 2-space indentation specified in my ESLint configuration.

My question is: Is there a way to configure WebStorm to enforce the code formatting based on my ESLint rules *without introducing Prettier* into the mix? I'm aiming for the cleanest and least-configured solution possible.